# gganimate package in R cannot link to ImageMagick

Tags: r, ggplot2, imagemagick

Running the awesome [gganimate](https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate) package, but can't get the base example to work.

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
theme_set(theme_bw())
p <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent, frame = year)) + geom_point() + scale_x_log10()
gg_animate(p)
```

Returns:

```
sh: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16\convert.exe: command not found
Error in cmd.fun(sprintf("%s --version", shQuote(ani.options("convert"))),  :   error in running command
sh: convert: command not found
Error in cmd.fun(sprintf("%s --version", convert), intern = TRUE) : 
  error in running command
I cannot find ImageMagick with convert = 'convert'
Error in file(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In im.convert(img.files, output = movie.name, convert = convert,  :
  Please install ImageMagick first or put its bin path into the system PATH > variable
2: In normalizePath(movie.name) :
  path[1]="file4421bbcfb7d.gif": No such file or directory
3: In file(file, "rb") :
  cannot open file > '/var/folders/4y/5nw21h2j1dz9p960gfvl16ywlrpqh8/T//RtmpRywpkt/gganimate/file4421bb> cfb7d.gif': No such file or directory
```

I'm almost sure ImageMagick is installed. What is the missing link?

Comment: Did you declare `convert.exe` in your Windows PATH?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Interesting comment.

Comment: The original install and path of ImageMagick was indeed off - I reinstalled, restarted, and the issue was gone. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone explain this answer in more detail? How and where do you make the change? The animate package works fine, but gganimate produces the error mentioned here